# Audit log to duplicated table with nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, audit

We have a web app where we use NHibernate as a ORM, and now we need to add auditing on some of the entities to track who changed what. However, I have not managed to figure out the best and easiest way to handle it.

If possible I would like the audit info to go into a separate table for each entity, something like this (pseudo sql):

```
create table MethodStatus (MethodId, Enabled)
create table MethodStatusAudit (MethodId, Enabled, AdminId, Date, ChangeType(U,D,I))
```

The question is how to setup this with (Fluent)NHibernate so that its somewhat easy to manage?

My initial idea was to use a IPreInsertEventListener / IPreUpdateEventListener / IPreDeleteEventListener and have my auditable objects implement a IAuditable interface and then do something. But I cant figure out how to save the audit..

```
public interface IAuditable {}

public class MethodStatus : IAuditable
{
    public virtual int MethodId { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Enabled { get; set; }
}

public class MethodStatusMap : ClassMap<MethodStatus>
{
    public MethodStatusMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.MethodId);
        Map(x => x.Enabled);
    }
}

public bool OnPreInsert(PreInsertEvent @event)
{
    var e = @event.Entity as IAuditable;
    if (e != null)
        //save audit.. but how? 
}
```

Comment: This is something more easily done in the database with triggers. Isn't this an option for you?

Comment: You can get the session object from @event.  Can you save your new objects with that?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I actually created a trigger-based solution first, but we would prefer to keep it up in the c# code. A trigger solution would be very "hidden" from the developers when everything else is up in C# code. It would also create a bit of a problem as we would need to send in the adminId that the database doesnt know about in someway so it can be inserted into the audit table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[NHibernate Envers](https://bitbucket.org/RogerKratz/nhibernate.envers/) helps you with that.